# what does "Needy-Greedy" mean?

Tags: meaning, errors

Hi I was watching a online video and the lecturer mentioned "here comes the needy-greedy detail of this lecture" after the introduction. And I am not quite sure what does the needy-greedy mean here? lots of information which cater the audience's appetites?

Comment: I believe the term you are looking for is _nitty-gritty_.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a non-native speaker's mishearing of *nitty-gritty*. Defined as [*Informal* - **the basic facts of a matter, situation, etc.; the core***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nitty-gritty)

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's possible that the error was mispronunciation rather than mishearing, but either way I agree with closing the question.

Comment: @Bradd: It's simply not credible that a lecturer would mispronounce such a term in such a context. Unless he's a non-native speaker himself, in which case I would still say that ***he*** (the lecturer who *isn't a native speaker of English*) must have misheard it.

Comment: I can easily imagine a native Japanese or Indian speaker pronouncing I's that way simply as a matter of accent.

Answer (score 3):

The term is, as commonly used in the American lexicon, "nitty-gritty". The term generally has the meaning of "at the heart or center of the matter" and the connotation of referring to the essential low-level details of some concept.

The etymology of the word is suspect, but first came into collective usage in the early 1960s and is believed to have ethnically-related (read; racist) origins, though today the term is perceived as innocent and unbiased.

Comment: "Grit" is dirt, and "nits" are lice eggs.  If you're worried about lice and dirt, you are down to the nitty-gritty.  There is no ethnic connotation to the word or its etymology *except* that the first time it was recorded in print was a quotation from an official of the NAACP.

Answer (score 0):

To add to KiethS's answer:  it's an example of a rhyming word term, like "itsy-bitsy"(there's probably a name for them).

PS:  There's a relatively well-known (but not by me) American music group called the Nitty Gritty Dirt Band (without the hyphen).